# Finding expired credit cards

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I have a query that finds the last credit card expiration date on file for a customer.  Customers may have more than one credit card on file.

This much works. lastcc is in YYMM format.

```
SELECT
dbo.xccard.CustId, 'xxxxx' as Name,
Max(substring(ExpDate,3,2) +
substring(ExpDate,1,2)) AS lastcc
FROM
dbo.xccard
INNER JOIN dbo.Customer ON dbo.Customer.CustId = dbo.xccard.CustId
INNER JOIN dbo.SOHeader ON dbo.Customer.CustId = dbo.SOHeader.CustID

WHERE SOHeader.Status <> 'C'
and Customer.Status ='A'
and Terms = 'CC'

GROUP BY
dbo.xccard.CustId,
dbo.Customer.Name

ORDER BY lastcc
```

I want to limit the results to those where the lastcc is less than the current month.

I think I need to do a subquery such that it would search from the table generated by the query above based on today's YYMM, but I am totally lost.

Something like

```
Select CustId, Name, lastcc in (

SELECT
    dbo.xccard.CustId, 'xxxxx' as Name,
    Max(substring(ExpDate,3,2) +
    substring(ExpDate,1,2)) AS lastcc
    FROM
    dbo.xccard
    INNER JOIN dbo.Customer ON dbo.Customer.CustId = dbo.xccard.CustId
    INNER JOIN dbo.SOHeader ON dbo.Customer.CustId = dbo.SOHeader.CustID

    WHERE SOHeader.Status <> 'C'
    and Customer.Status ='A'
    and Terms = 'CC'

    GROUP BY
    dbo.xccard.CustId,
    dbo.Customer.Name

    ORDER BY lastcc
    )

WHERE lastcc > '1701'
```

I also tried:

I also tried this

```
Select CustId, Name, lastcc in (



WHERE lastcc > '1701'

AND
dbo.xccard_all_FullLookUp.CustId in (
SELECT
    dbo.xccard.CustId, 'xxxxx' as Name,
    Max(substring(ExpDate,3,2) +
    substring(ExpDate,1,2)) AS lastcc
    FROM
    dbo.xccard
    INNER JOIN dbo.Customer ON dbo.Customer.CustId = dbo.xccard.CustId
    INNER JOIN dbo.SOHeader ON dbo.Customer.CustId = dbo.SOHeader.CustID

    WHERE SOHeader.Status <> 'C'
    and Customer.Status ='A'
    and Terms = 'CC'

    GROUP BY
    dbo.xccard.CustId,
    dbo.Customer.Name


    )
```

Can someone help?  Many thanks

Comment: What format is `ExpDate` in? Why isn't it stored as a date, since that's what it is (and obviously that's how you're using it)?

Comment: ExpDate is in MMYY format, a string.

Comment: Ah, I see, I was trying to figure out why you were parsing it. It's simply to reverse month and year so you can keep treating this like a string. You really should consider storing a date instead of a 4-character string, IMHO.

Comment: If it was my system I would.  I am working with a corporate system.

Comment: This is going to be terrible for performance but try `WHERE CONVERT(datetime, '01'+ExpDate, 3) < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1);`

Comment: how about cast(left(expdate,2) + '/1/'+right(expdate,2) as date)

Comment: Trying Aaron's approache I tried changing the last line of my first try  to:
    
    WHERE CONVERT(datetime, '01'+ExpDate, 3) < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1)

but I got "
[Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'in'.
42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'."

Comment: if you use CONVERT with a datetime with style 12 you get yymmdd format.. so you could do `where lastcc < convert(varchar(4), getdate(), 12)`

Comment: Something must be wrong because I keep getting  the error 
[Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'in'.
42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'. In other words, the problem seems to be with the subquery syntax rather than the subquery itself.